# GoCoder SDK - not creating the stream file

Tags: wowza

I have an iPhone app which users can broadcast their camera to other users.

I have a self hosted Wowza Streaming Engine server.

I'm using GoCoder SDK and have couple of issues or maybe things that I did not understand:

1. I configure the connection parameters with a new generated StreamName but my expectation is that the SDK will create the streamFile in Wowza stream files, but it does not. It says that everything is ok but when I go to Wowza StreamFile nothing is in there.
2. If I create manually the stream file with the stream uri in advance than I can see the phone camera stemming, but I just don't get it how can I manage different users streaming if I need to create the stream files in advanced?
3. I was able to connect the streamFile I created in advanced with stream uri "wowz://host:port" to the live application but not to the webrtc application which I need it to present in my web site. Is there any limitation here?

I tried hard to find in Wowza docs some explanations on how things should works but with no success :-(